# Export table with random rows and columns (defined by an object) to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reflection, parameters

I have a task that I am sure can be easily generalized in a simple way.

I have different tables to be exported to excel dynamically, and what I am doing is creating the table columns in HTML from the Object parameters, and the rows using a foreach on the List to create the rows.

So for example if I have a list of Customer (`List<Customer>` ) 
I create the tr basing on the amount and name of the Object properties:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int DeliveryAddressId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    ....
}

var output = "<table>";
        output += "<thead>";
        output += "<tr>";
        output += "<th>DeliveryAddressId </th>";
        .....
```

and the foreach to fill in the rows:

```
foreach (var customer in List<Customer>)
        {
            output += "<tr>";
            output += "<td>" + customer.DeliveryAddressId + "</td>";
            .....
```

But then I have different objects with different parameters, so the question is:

How can I create a generic method that takes a `List<Object>` as input and create this kind of table using the object parameter names as columns name and then cycles the rows accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create a generic method that accepts a list of `T`

```
public string DumpToTable<T>(List<T> list) {
}
```

You could enumerate all public properties on T like so:

```
var props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public);
```

Depending on your use case, you might want to make that `.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);` to filter out inherited members.

For each `PropertyInfo` element, you can then access their `.Name`, when generating the header.

After that, iterating through the list, you'd have to invoke their relative `.GetValue` methods:

```
foreach(T item in list) {
    string line = "";
    foreach(PropertyInfo prop in props) {
         line += string.Format("<td>{0}</td>", prop.GetValue(item));
    }
    output += string.Format("<tr>{0}</tr>", line);
}
```

Comment: The sweetness I was looking for. Thanks